# Questions are displayed with more text - change the style

Tags: support, design, user-interface, information-display

I changed a setting on the web site, and I do not remember which one it was.

Now I do not like it. How do I change the displayed questions style (screenshots from Stack Overflow)?

**Currently they are like this:**

[image]

**I want them like this:**

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently can't change how the questions are shown.

The compact view with only titles is how questions are shown on [the homepage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). The expanded view with an excerpt of the question is how posts are shown on all other [question pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions).

It was possible at one point with the new nav to switch between both views, which I assume is where the confusion comes from. But the new nav [has been retired](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359643/1990216) and you can't change the setting any more.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by manually tweaking the style of elements and moving elements around.

You can do that by creating [custom CSS rules](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) and [injecting custom JavaScript](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en). (those are for Chrome, but these days any modern browser should have such tools.)

I do not see any need for Stack Exchange to do that for us, those who want a custom view should tweak what the server gives them themselves, .e.g. using the above tools.

Comment: I have simply changed a setting in the web site and I do not remember which one it was. Now the questions are not the way I want.

Comment: @Vityata if you refer to Stack Overflow only, then they disabled the "new nav" yesterday. I'm afraid you can't get it back. More details: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0

Comment: That's really a pity. I completely do not understand it.

Comment: @Vityata it was a failed experiment. The real mistake was letting it stay for so long, having people getting used to it, when it was obvious it was going to be shut down at some point. Someone on SE management just made a big mistake, that's all.

Comment: Good to see that I am not the only one who did not like it :) Thanks.